# Math formula editor that can be plugged into any website

Tags: web-services, math, editor

I am writing a Q and A web application. I'm wondering if there's any library of web services that can allow user to create math equations easily in the web editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is a javascript utility that will let your users enter formulas and equations in LaTeX or MathML (the two most common languages for typesetting math).

Answer (score 2):

'[How do I type mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/faq#latex)' from [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/)  *might* help you. In short, they use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).